# How do I stub a chain of methods in Sinon?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I know how to use stub to replace one function.

```
sandbox.stub(Cars, "findOne",
            () => {return car1 });
```

But now I have a line in my function I want to test that I need to stub that looks like this

```
Cars.find().fetch()
```

So there is a chain of function here and I'm unsure what I need to do. How do I stub "find" to return something that I can use to stub "fetch"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
sandbox.stub(Cars, "find", () => {
    return {
        fetch: sinon.stub().returns(anything);
    };
});
```

Comment: Got `stub(obj, 'meth', fn) has been removed, see documentation`

Comment: it is useful to add that Sinon suggests to:
Use sandbox.stub(obj, 'meth').callsFake(fn) instead in order to stub a function.
Use sandbox.stub(obj, 'meth').value(fn) instead in order to stub a non-function value.

Comment: What if the chain is longer than one? `Car.createQueryBuilder().where().getMany()`

Answer (score 30):

IMHO, we can just use `returns` to do this. We don't need to use `callsFake` or mock it as function.

```
// Cars.find().fetch()

sinon.stub(Cars, 'find').returns({
  fetch: sinon.stub().returns(anything)
});
```

in case, if there is another method after **fetch()**, we can use `returnsThis()`

```
// Cars.find().fetch().where()

sinon.stub(Cars, 'find').returns({
  fetch: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
  where: sinon.stub().returns(anything)
});
```

Ref:
https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.3.3/

Hope it helps

Comment: This is awesome and should be in the Sinon docs explicitly for how to verify chained methods. I have been trying in vain for a day to test that the correct Joi validator was applied and this solved my problem, e.g. `sinon.stub(Joi, 'array').returns({ min: sinon.stub().returnsThis(), required: sinon.stub().returns('anything'), });` to mock `Joi.array().min(1).required()`

Comment: How can I assert that `fetch` was called? Will `assert(Cars.find().fetch.calledOnce)` work?

Answer (score 4):

The form of attaching a function to a stub shown here:

```
sandbox.stub(Cars, "find", () => {
    return {
        fetch: sinon.stub().returns(anything);
    };
});
```

is deprecated.

It's now, as of [version 6.3](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.3.3/stubs/)

```
sandbox.stub(Cars, "find").callsFake(() => {
    return {
        fetch: sinon.stub().returns(anything);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach that also allows spying on chains of jQuery methods - which took me a long time to figure out.

In the example, I am trying to test that an email field is cleared out

```
    //set up stub and spy
    const valSpy = sandbox.spy();
    const jQueryStub = sandbox
      .stub($.prototype, "find")       // this prototype is important
      .withArgs("input[name=email]")
      .returns({ val: valSpy });

    // call function under test
    learnerAlreadyAccepted(inviteDoc);

    // check expectations
    expect(jQueryStub).to.have.been.called;      // not really necessary
    expect(valSpy).to.have.been.calledWith("");
```

and the function under test is (roughly):

```
  learnerAlreadyAccepted = function(doc) {
    $("form").find("input[name=email]").val("");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and, though I liked the solution for a single test, wanted something more dynamic that would allow for reuse across tests. I also preferred the sandbox approach, as it made restoring much easier for larger suites. End result:

```js
export function setupChainedMethodStub(sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox, obj: any, methodName: string, methodChain: string[], value: any) {
    return sandbox.stub(obj, methodName).returns(generateReturns(sandbox, methodChain, value));
}

function generateReturns(sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox, methodChain: string[], value: any): any {
    if (methodChain.length === 1) {
        return {
            [methodChain[0]]: sandbox.stub().returns(value),
        };
    } else {
        return {
            [methodChain[0]]: sandbox.stub().returns(generateReturns(sandbox, methodChain.slice(1), value)),
        };
    }
}
```

Wherever I want to set up a stub on the fly, I pass in the created sandbox and the other parameters:

`setupChainedMethodStub(sandbox, MyMongooseModel, 'findOne', ['sort', 'exec'], { foo: 'bar' })`

Then I just have a `sandbox.restore()` in my highest scoped `afterEach()`

Comment: So your snippet stubs MyMongooseModel.sort().exec().findeOne() method. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The order is a bit off. It would actually stub MyMongooseModel.findOne().sort().exec(). I realize sort doesn't make sense after findOne in practical application, but this was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few changes from v2.0.

[More details here](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v3.3.0/migrating-to-2.0/)

One of them is:

`stub(obj, 'meth', fn) has been removed, see documentation`

You can downgrade but I would not recommend it, instead you can do something like this:

```js
let stub = sinon.stub(obj, "meth").callsFake(() => {
  return {
    meth2: sinon.stub().callsFake(() => {
      return {
        meth3: sinon.stub().returns(yourFixture),
      };
    }),
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution that hopefully works for others.

Presuming that `fetch` is also a method on `Cars`, and `fetch` and `find` support method chaining, `Cars` may look something like this:

```
class Cars {
  fetch() {
    // do stuff
    return this;
  }

  find() {
    // do stuff
    return this;
  }
}
```

[ANSWER] We should be able to support method chaining with the stub like this:

```
  sandbox.stub(Cars, 'fetch').callsFake(function () { return this; }); // optional
  sandbox.stub(Cars, 'findOne').callsFake(function () { return this; });
```