# Sinon stubs for chained methods

Tags: node.js, sinon

I'm looking to unit test chained methods for a weather API (https://github.com/eliashussary/dark-sky/blob/master/dark-sky-api.js). Here is my simplified code. What it does is for a given location (object with longitude and latitude) it returns all current weather warnings.

```
// weather.js

const DarkSky = require('dark-sky');
const darksky = new DarkSky('API_KEY');

async function getWeatherWarnings(location) {
    const data = await darksky
                   .coordinates(location)
                   .exclude('currently,minutely,hourly,daily,flags')
                   .get();

    return data.alerts;
}

module.exports = {
    getWeatherWarnings,
};
```

Note that `get()` returns a promise. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948135/how-do-i-stub-a-chain-of-methods-in-sinon/52359957#52359957) stackoverflow answer and so I did the following for the unit test:

```
// test/weather.js

const { getWeatherWarnings } = require('../weather');
const DarkSky  = require('dark-sky');
const darksky = new DarkSky('key');
const { assert } = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');

const result = [{
          title: 'Dust Storm Warning',
          regions: [Array],
          severity: 'warning',
          time: 1568508240,
          expires: 1568509200,
          description: 'A DUST STORM WARNING REMAINS IN EFFECT UNTIL 600 PM MST'
}];

describe('get weather warning', () => {
  it('maricopa county', async () => {

    sinon.stub(darksky, 'coordinates').returns({
      exclude: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      get: sinon.stub().resolves(result)  
    });

    const response = await getWeatherWarnings({ lat: 33.0435719, lng: -112.0667759 });
    console.log('response: ' + response);
    assert.equal(response, result);
  });
});
```

The test fails. I added a `console.log` and `response` returns undefined. This suggests the stub did not take effect. What am I missing? I'm using sinon 7.4.2.

I realize this is a contrived example but it's just to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging I got this solution:

```
describe('get weather warning', () => {
  it('maricopa county', async () => {
    const darkskystub = sinon.stub(DarkSky.prototype, 'coordinates').returns({
      exclude: sinon.stub().returns({
        get: sinon.stub().resolves(weatherResult)
      })
    });

    const response = await getFrostAndRainWarnings({
      lat: 33.0435719,
      lng: -112.0667759
    });

    assert.equal(darkskystub.calledOnce, true);
    assert.deepEqual(response, warningResult);
});
```