# How to mock a chained function call in Sinon

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

how do you mock using Sinon something like this?

```
const data = await getData(); 
const res= await data.collection('myCollection').deleteOne({ id: 12 });
```

Comment: How about: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/59up8qdr/ ?

Comment: thanks you. but how to chekck if the the method updatedone is called?

Comment: How do you then check if deleteone is actually called?

Comment: With a spy! See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/1dgnyju8/

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948135/how-do-i-stub-a-chain-of-methods-in-sinon/52359957

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [`.returnsThis()`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/#stubreturnsthis), which simply returns the function's `this` just like fluent APIs like this do, and is intended specifically for stubbing such APIs.

You can use it like so:

```js
const db = require('...')

async function test() {
  // Setup
  const fakeResponse = {
    collection: Sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
    deleteOne: Sinon.stub().returnsThis()
  }
  Sinon.stub(db, 'getData').resolves(fakeResponse)
  
  // Call your code that does stuff
  const data = await db.getData(); 
  const res = await data.collection('myCollection').deleteOne({ id: 12 })
  
  // Assert
  Sinon.assert.calledWith(fakeResponse.collection, 'myCollection')
  Sinon.assert.calledWith(fakeResponse.deleteOne, { id: 12 })
}
```

I'm assuming here that `getData` is a method on some object, say `db`. If not you'll have to figure out some other way to stub `getData()`.